# Sorting date (Y-M-D h-m-s) not sorting correctly

Tags: javascript, date

I have a list of objects that I want to sort by date of creation.
Here is my relevant code:

```
  dateToLocalString(date) {
    date = new Date(date);
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const month = date.getMonth() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMonth() : date.getMonth();
    const day = date.getDate() < 10 ? "0" + date.getDate() : date.getDate();
    const hours = date.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + date.getHours() : date.getHours();
    const minutes = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes();
    const seconds = date.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + date.getSeconds() : 
    date.getSeconds();

    return `${year}-${month}-${day} ${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  }

 const AscOrder = function x(order) {
      return function(a, b) {
        if(order === 'status') {
          if(a[order].split(' ')[1] < b[order].split(' ')[1]) return -1;
          if(a[order].split(' ')[1] > b[order].split(' ')[1]) return 1;
          return 0;
        }
        if(a[order] < b[order]) return -1;
        if(a[order] > b[order]) return 1;
        return 0;
      };
    };


switch (this.state.sortDevSpacesBy) {
  case 'CREATED' : devSpaceList.sort(AscOrder('createdAt'));
    break;
  case 'CREATED_DESC' : devSpaceList.sort(DescOrder('createdAt'));
    break;
}
```

But it doesn not sort my dates correctly, Y-M-D is sorted correctly, but then there seems to be a problem with the time:

Descending order:
 - 2018-04-24 12:53:50
 - 2018-05-15 15:21:15
 - 2018-05-15 15:03:04
 - 2018-05-15 11:55:07

Comment: do you have an iso date? if so, you could sort by string, without some other tools.

Comment: I think that you should try to provide a shorter and more concise example

Comment: I reduced the size of the example. @Nina Scholz I have no idea if it is an ISO date, I will have a look thanks.

Comment: @Jérémy, have a look: [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reasons like this, I usually convert all dates to time since epoch before sorting; e.g.:

```
let d = new Date()
d.getTime() //-> 1529070578437
```

This effectively removes lots of tricky edge cases (such as leap years) and other complex conversion routines.

I work with the dates as much as possible in this format, and convert only when necessary; e.g., displaying to User in their locale format.

Comment: That´s a bit tricky because I am changing the structure of my date this way: `${year}-${month}-${day} ${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}` . And if I use getTime() it removes the date and keeps only the time, it is normal I guess, but  Idont see how it can help me.

Comment: ^ o.O? getTime() gives you milliseconds (ms) since epoch: 01 Jan 1970 00:00:000. Use that for sorting and then use the other methods to display in your preferred format.

Comment: And remember, "Time is an illusion, lunchtime doubly so."  --Douglas Adams, Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy.

Comment: Oh yes I got it, thank you! I was a bit confused with the word epoch, as a french speaker, this was unknowned to me. Ahah Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy, that s a funny reference!

Comment: ^ Like. Glad that I was able to help. No need to write all that tricky sorting code; this should make your life a lot easier. Also, probably best to use a canned sorting routine instead of rolling your own. You should be able to use some (n)log(n) complexity sort from some library (lodash, underscore, etc.)